# Easy Django REST Framework Websocket Usage

Tags: angularjs, django, websocket

I have a an application that uses Angular for the frontend and communicates with an API running Django RF.

Now, let me try and outline what I'm trying to achieve in hopes of finding an easy solution.

When a user runs a report, a worker version of the API generates the report to prevent the main API from bogging down. The report runs for a couple seconds/minutes. The user refreshes the page and voila, their report is there.

What I'm trying to achieve is the elimination of the whole "user refreshes the page" portion of this process.

My goal is to do this via websockets.

I literally want something as simple as:

- WEB: "Hey API, I want this report. I'll wait."
- API: "Yo dog, you're reports done."
- WEB: "Cool, let me refresh my report list. Thanks bud."

Now, we start to venture into an area I'm unfamiliar with. Websockets can do this, right? I just need to create a connection and wait for the all-clear to be sent by the worker.

Now, here's where it gets hairy.

I've spent the better part of the day going through libraries and just can't find what I need. The closest I've come is [this](https://github.com/Kocal/django-tornado-websockets), but it clashes with restframework. I get hit with tons of 404 errors and I think it has to do with the way rf manages urls.

I literally need a simple event listener. There's got to be a better way, right? To clarify, I don't want to do something brute-force like silently ping the API for report status. That gets a tad hinky. I want the API to tell me when it's ready.

Comment: Did you consider to simply write code on the angular side to call the GET API every day, 10sec until done?

Answer (score 0):

In a basic way, can use something like [`django-websocket-redis`](https://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and use Django signals to pass the messages around. ws4redis handles alot of the tricky bit. However, websockets are weird and honestly I doubt you need them. You could just poll some route that has the job state. If you need to get it done fast, I would go that route.